# MSBuild target should be different when running in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have it defined for MSBuild to run unit tests and metrics after build:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="RunUnitTests;RunCodeMetrics;StageFiles"/>
```

but if the build is run from Azure DevOps (a.k.a. VSTS), tests and metrics are defined as separate steps. How would I define targets based on where MSBuild is going to run?

Comment: If you're in VSTS I would tend to use the built-in tasks for running tests instead of hiding it all within a single msbuild script.  The built-in task automatically harvests the test results back into the build information for easy viewing.

Comment: Setting that aside, msbuild has a last-defined-wins approach to redefining targets.  You could create targets files based on your environment that override certain targets.  So on dev you could import dev.targets which defines targets for RunUnitTests, RunCodeMetrics and StageFiles.

Comment: Another option might be to run them as separate msbuild steps within the VSTS run.  Use the /t:RunUnitTests in one, /t:RunCodeMetrics in another and /t:StageFiles in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having this Condition in my targets file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(AzureDevOps)' != 'true'" DependsOnTargets="RunUnitTests;RunCodeMetrics;StageFiles" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(AzureDevOps)' == 'true'" DependsOnTargets="StageFiles"/>
```

When build is started from cloud, MSBuild argument is added:

```
/p:AzureDevOps=true
```

Comment: Environment variable TF_BUILD is available by default. No need to pass argument via build command for that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services